# DynamoDB: is it possible to Query array of specific items with the same PK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I want to get an array of **specific items** with the same `Primary Key (pk)` and different `Sort Keys (sk)`.

Let's suppose that the keys of these items look like this:

```js
[
  { pk: 1, sk: 1 },
  { pk: 1, sk: 3 },
  { pk: 1, sk: 6 }
]
```

`Batch Get` request of these items looks like this:

```js
{
  RequestItems: {
    'TABLE_NAME': {
      Keys: [
        { pk: 1, sk: 1 },
        { pk: 1, sk: 3 },
        { pk: 1, sk: 6 }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Is it possible to get them by `Query` or do I have to use `Batch Get` command?

Comment: what's wrong with Batch Get?

Comment: I read in [this article](https://dynobase.dev/dynamodb-scan-vs-query/) that if I want to get **Collection** of items that have **the same PK** I should use Query (it is shown on the graph) but I didn't find any implementation of that case. Maybe this article is misleading or I didn't understand it correctly? I'm new to DynamoDB

Comment: That article says you shouldn't use Scan - it doesn't say you shouldn't use Batch Get.

Comment: On the graph, it says: "Are these items using the same partition key?". If yes "use **Query**", if no "use **BatchGetItem** or a bunch of **GetItem**". Doesn't that suggest that Query should be the correct option? In my case, all the items have the same partition key.

Comment: I see. I don't understand why it says that, since it looks like Query returns sort keys in a particular range, not multiple. E.g. "1 to 4" rather than "1, 3 and 6"

Comment: Yup, that's why I was wondering if it is even possible cause I didn't find any example of this kind of Query

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR  You probably want `BatchGetItem`.

With a `Query`, you can define your `sk` with a [condition expression](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.html#Query.KeyConditionExpressions) that can return multiple items, as in `pk = 1 AND sk <= 6`.  Primary key schema are often chosen to take advantage of this pattern.  In your case, though, it's doubtful a single `sk` expression will be able to exactly match your arbitrary specific items.  As @RossWilliams points out, `Query` does give you the option to overfetch with a broad `sk > 0` condition and then [filter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.html#Query.FilterExpression) the results.

So the fallback is `BatchGetItem`, for which you specify arbitrary pairs of `pk` and `sk` values.  You'll get back 1 item for each primary key pair found in the table.

Here's a summary:

| Operation | Primary Key conditions | # Items Returned if Found |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [Query](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html) | `pk equals` and `sk =, >=, begins_with,` [etc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.html#Query.KeyConditionExpressions) | one or many |
| [GetItem](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_GetItem.html) | `pk equals` and `sk equals` | one |
| [BatchGetItem](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchGetItem.html) | List of `[pk equals` and `sk equals]` | one per List entry |

Answer (score 1):

No. Queries using a sort key can only get items within a range of values.

You can apply a `filterExpression` and use the `IN` keyword to limit items to a set of specific values.

This approach has downsides:

1. Query can only read 1 MB of data at once. If the query range exceeds 1 MB, you might not read all the data you need.
2. You will pay for each 4KB of data queried. If your items are very small, and you know you will not be filtering out most items queried, this could save you money. But it could also cost you more if these conditions are not met.
3. Creating a filter expression string is more annoying than a batch get.